# Mixed-Design ANOVA Confusion: Do I separate my treatment Column?

Tags: anova, spss, two-way, variable

[image]In this particular study, I had 40 experimental subjects which were randomly allocated to 2 treatment groups. After the initial treatment, each where randomised to receive 2 other treatments. So the grouping are as follow

Vehicle ( n=20) ==> Vehicle-Haloperidol (n=10), Vehicle-Control ( n=10) 
compund x (n=20)==> Compund x-Haloperidol (n=10), compund x-Control ( n=10)

Then these groups underwent a behavioural task which has 2 levels. 
When entering the data in SPSS, can I assume that I have 4 treatment groups and put all of them in 1 coloumn ? or Should I assume I have 2 separate treatment factors and put them in separate coloumns ? Is there a statistical best practice for this?

[image]

Comment: I do not fully understand your question, but in SPSS the mixed-design anova requires Data to be in wide-format. This means each experimental unit (participants) gets one row and all measurements for this unit are stored in this one row.
Something like this:

Participant 1; Group 1; Measurement Time 1; Measurement Time 2; ..., Measurement Time x.   |   
Participant 2; Group 1; Measurement Time 1; Measurement Time 2; ...; Measurement Time x   |   
Participant 3; Group 2; Measurement Time 1; Measurement Time 2; ...; Measurement Time x

and so on :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Perhaps I could clarify my question with the following images I will include in my question space.

Comment: I think that helps. 
So you got 3 Factors. 
Factor 1: Threatment 1 (which is a between subject factor).
Factor 2: Threatment 2 (which is a between subject factor).
Factor 3: left/right (which is a within subject factor). 

If each row in picture 2 represents one participant i'd say your data is perfectly fine. 

1 combined Group Factor vs 2 seperat: 
The benefit of not grouping them together is, that you get information about each treatment alone as well (Maineffects of Factor 1 und 2). Maybe its just the first treatment alone that makes a difference, maybe its just the second alone?

Comment: This is Excellent . Thank you so much. I just needed someone explain to me in a different way. So baslically it goes back to what the initial experimental question is... Neither is wrong. but one suits the question more. Thanks so much :)